# How to solve : Parameter validation failed for "q"

Tags: c#, xml, google-translate

I need to use google translate api, but it translate just 100 line for me. Actually i have 5000 line, and i have to give 5000 line. There may be a quota problem, but I know 10M in 100 seconds.

I would be very happy if you help me. thanks.

After translate 100 lines it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjF8C.png)

my api code:

```
public static string TranslateText(string data) //Google translate API 
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    //Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"(--api key path--)");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"(--api key path--);
    string Pathsave = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
    TranslationClient client = TranslationClient.Create();

    string translate_result = client.TranslateText(data, "en", "de").TranslatedText;
    return translate_result;
}
```

**code that caused the Exception;**

```
public string EditText_Product(XDocument xDocument)
{
        try
        {
            var stbu = new StringBuilder();

            stbu.AppendLine("asdasdasd");

            string a, b, c, d, e, vid;


            SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
            ("data source= --database path --");

            if (sql_con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                sql_con.Open();

            foreach (XElement root in xDocument.Descendants("Root"))
            {

                foreach (XElement products in root.Descendants("PRODUCTS"))
                {

                    foreach (XElement product in products.Descendants("PRODUCT"))
                    {
                        a = (string)product.Element("A");
                        a = StripHTML(a);
                        a = TranslateText(a);

                        b = (string)product.Element("B");
                        b = StripHTML(B);
                        if (b != null)
                        {
                            b = TranslateText(b).Trim();
                        }


                        c = (string)product.Element("C");
                        c = StripHTML(c);
                        if (c != null)
                        {
                            c = TranslateText(C).Trim();
                        }



                        foreach (XElement options in product.Descendants("OPTIONS"))
                        {
                            foreach (XElement option in options.Descendants("OPTION"))
                            {

                                d = (string)option.Element("D");
                                d = StripHTML(d);

                                e = (string)option.Element("E");
                                e = StripHTML(e).Trim();

                                vid = (string)option.Element("VID");


                                if (BarcodeExist_Product(vid) == false)
                                {

                                    stbu.AppendLine(stokkodu + "," + "default_family" + "," + "enabled" + "," + "simple" + "," + "each" + "," + "in_stock" +
                                                    "," + "3" + "," + "1" + "," + "1" + "," + "item" + "," + "1" + "," + "1" + "," + "1" + "," + "" + "," + a +
                                                    "," + "system" + "," + a + "," + "" + "," + b + "," + "system" + "," + b + "," + "" + "," +
                                                    c + "," + "system" + "," + c + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "1" + "," + "1" + "," + "" +
                                                    "," + "" + "," + "system" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "system" + "," + "" +
                                                    "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "system" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," +
                                                    "system" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "");

                                    WriteToFile_Product(stbu.ToString());

                                    SaveToDB_Product(vid);
                                }                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sql_con.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that caused the Exception, inside the TRY block

Comment: Your id google is not valid.  The q parameter is the user id and you need to use a valid id.

Comment: Why are you setting the environment variable with a value, then reading that value back out of the environment variables?

Comment: @MahmoudSayed i did

Comment: @jdweng How do I translate 100 rows if there is no valid ID?

Comment: @Amy just i read api documentation, like this

Comment: You need to get a valid id/key from google.

Comment: @jdweng ok but my key is not valid? if not valid how do i get 100 line translated ??

Comment: @jdweng: No, the `q` parameter is *not* the ID, it's the query to be translated. See https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate

Comment: It seems very unlikely that your XML code is particularly relevant here. You should capture the string that's causing the problem, and put that in a [mcve].

Comment: As another alternative, you might want to try using Google.Cloud.Translation.V3, which we recently released. If the problem is due to URL encoding or similar (which would probably be a bug in Google.Cloud.Translate.V2, and I still want to know about) then Google.Cloud.Translation.V3 may work, as that's gRPC-based.

Comment: @JonSkeet  as I said before, i get 100 line translated, but i have to get 5000 line just about. thank you jon, i will try V3.

Comment: @efe: So which line is failing? Is it the same one every time? That's what I'd expect, in which case the previous ones that work are probably irrelevant. I can imagine it being rate limiting or a quota issue, but I'd expect the error message to be clearer in that case.

Comment: @JonSkeet 

I did.. There is a empty section between the "B" tags after 100 line , it gives an exception when it comes empty. Actually there is <![CDATA[]]> tag between "B" tags, this not null, this is must be " ". 

if i check like this  if(B==" ") {B = " "}, this is working.

Comment: @JonSkeet

I've always checked  ==>  if(B== null) before, but this is not correct way. it should be done like  ==>  if(B==" ")

Comment: Well yes, those do very different things. I suspect at this point it's best to delete the question - either that, or edit it to include a [mcve] - and then answer it yourself.